# Make WIT field only editable by a small group of users

Tags: azure-devops

We have a WIT field that is supposed to be changed by only a distinct group of contributors in our project.

We tried something like this, where the members of "IdeaSiteAdmins" are supposed to be able to edit the WIT field:

```
<READONLY for="[PROJECT]\Readers" not="[PROJECT]\IdeaSiteAdmins" />
```

Which raises the following error:

> Error:
>   Precondition Failed
>
> Line  : VS403667: Custom project scoped
>   groups are not allowed. Only built-in project groups 'Readers,
>   Contributors, Build Administrators, Project Administrators' are
>   allowed.
>
> Line 314 : VS237301: The process contains field rule
>   attributes "for" or "not" that reference Azure Active Directory (AAD)
>   groups, which is unsupported. The '[PROJECT]\Readers' group contains
>   the following AAD groups: [....]

Removing the `for="[PROJECT]\Readers"` leaves us with the first error.

Is there a way to use our custom group?

Comment: it seems to be an azure devops issue.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/521976/an-error-occurred-while-import-process-in-devops.html
I don't think it is solved..